# A Mathematical Tour of Budapest?

Tags: math-history

(This might be a better fit at the Travel site. If so, let me know and I'll flag it to have it migrated.)

I'm planning on taking a brief trip to Budapest soon. Many hugely influential mathematicians and physicists were born there - Erdös, Teller, Szilard, Von Neumann, etc. - and I was wondering if there are any sites in the city that would be worth visiting for someone with a background in their work. This could be as simple as a plaque commemorating any of these individuals or as elaborate as one of the universities where they worked. I've been searching online and haven't turned anything up yet, though perhaps that's because I don't speak Hungarian. :-)

Comment: Don't know about Budapest but if you ever go to Denmark, there's the [Niels Bohr Institute in Copenhagen](http://www.nbi.ku.dk/english/) and the [Tycho Brahe’s observatory](http://www.sciencetourist.co.uk/2014/02/the-16th-century-observatory-on-island.html) in the [island of Ven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ven,_Sweden).

Comment: The search terms "mathematician born budapest" led me quickly to [this](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/BirthplaceMaps/Budapest.html). After that things get a bit more difficult. I looked for Lóránd Eötvös, because I know that there is a university named after him. There must be a plaque or statue of him. Seems there is also a museum, but the hungarian site is dead, and the only other site I could find is in dutch, so... Maybe the other names on the list are easier to track down. Good luck.

Comment: Have you found something? I would be interested to know. Maybe you could answer your own question... for posterity.

Comment: I am planning a trip to Budapest myself, so I have this same question.